# Can Spring Web Flow be used in non-UI contexts?

Tags: java, spring, workflow, spring-webflow, business-process-management

I have a need for a generic workflow builder. Something that builds workflows that automated processes (not end users) would then use like a BPM.

1. Can Spring Web Flow be used for non-UI purposes (in other words, just the workflow aspect)?
2. If so, is it possible to configure Spring Web Flow outside of Spring XML, and just as raw Java? If so, how? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently done some research on a similar requirement to handle workflow processing without implementing a heavy service like BPM.  The most likely candidate I found for processing was using Spring AOP and AspectJ to create the states of a workflow engine, define your transitions based on conditions in your pointcuts.

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Orchestration-Oleg-Zhurakousky)